# Django - ModelForm does not update on form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form for when a user makes a form submission an object with a bunch of fields are supposed to get updated in my application.

Currently, when a user makes a form submission with this form a new object gets made and I don’t know why.

I receive an error that says `“get() returned more than one User_Info -- it returned 2!”`

How do my I make my current form on the `myaccount_edit.html` page update the object correctly with my current code? The fields that get updated in the object are based on the logged in user.

I've tried many things but I'm kinda lost.

The form is located on `myaccount_edit.html`.

Where the form data display is on `myaccount.html`. That data displays correctly when there isn't an error.

Screenshot attached.

[image]

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Views:**

```
def account_view_myaccount(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'user_profile': user_profile
    } 

return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)



def account_view_myaccount_edit(request):
  form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
  user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)

  obj, created = User_Info.objects.update_or_create(user=request.user)
  user = request.user

if request.method == "POST":  # checking if request is POST or Not
    # if its a post request, then its checking if the form is valid or not
    if form.is_valid():
        listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
        listing_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance 
        listing_instance.save() # calling 'save()' method of model
        return redirect("myaccount_edit")


  context = {
      'form': form, 
      'user_profile': user_profile,
      'obj': obj
   }

return render(request, "myaccount_edit.html", context)
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('myaccount/', account_view_myaccount, name='myaccount'),   
   path('myaccount_edit/', account_view_myaccount_edit, name='myaccount_edit')
]
```

**models:**

```
class User_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
   image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)      
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)  

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Info"
```

Comment: You likely won't want a User to have more than one profile change user from Foreignkey to one to one field

Comment: Hi@Dante made that update and now I'm running into the error ``UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_user_info.user_id`` how do I resolve that?

Comment: Delete one of your data in admin panel and where do you exactly create the user info

Comment: Consider using` get_or_create` to avoid duplicates

Comment: I replaced using ``get_or_create``also commented out ``listing_instance.save()``... I get no errors but the object doesn't update.

Comment: You are not passing any new data from the form that is why nothing is changing. Pass `form. cleaned_data` in your update or create

Comment: @Dante I'm a bit lost. Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: I don't have my pc right now but wait abit let me see if I can arrange the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in form valid block

```
def update_view(request):
    instance = user_info.objects.get(user=request.user)

    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =HomeForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():

            listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
            listing_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance 
            listing_instance.save() 
            return redirect('success_url_name')  # Redirect to a success page
    else:
        form =HomeForm(instance=instance)
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

Comment: Apologies but where do i put ``data=form.cleaned_data``?

Comment: now i get ``local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`` and not sure why.

Comment: I edited the answer hope that helps

Comment: Sweet! thank you sir! You're a ninja! It works now with zero errors. The only field that doesn't update is the image upload field and I don't know why. That field updates in the admin panel just fine. What's that about?

Comment: I just added the image field. Thought it was included before.